# Convert NSData to signed integer

Tags: objective-c, nsdata

I have seen some similiar questions but I can't get this right:

I receive a 16 bit signed integer in an NSData object, e.g '0xFF3C'. How can I read out the correct number from this?

EDIT: With James Webster's answer I get:

```
Received hex value : <0800>
Converted value: 803995656
Received hex value : <0a00>
Converted value: 803995658
Received hex value : <1a00>
Converted value: 803995674
Received hex value : <faff>
Converted value: 804061178
Received hex value : <e4ff>
Converted value: 804061156
Received hex value : <f0ff>
Converted value: 804061168
```

which clearly is not correct (I expect +/- 2000)

EDIT: Some code:

```
-(void)characteristicValueRead:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic{

  unsigned short myInt = (int) [characteristic.value bytes];
  NSLog(@"Received value: %@", characteristic.value);
  NSLog(@"Converted value: %i",(int)myInt);
}
```

With this snippet I get:

```
Received value: <0000>
Converted value: 26176
Received value: <0000>
Converted value: 46688
Received value: <0000>
Converted value: 30576
Received value: <0000>
Converted value: 2656
Received value: <0000>
Converted value: 50896
Received value: <0000>
```

which looks really interesting/annoying. What could this come from?

Comment: Do you mean 0xFF3C, ergo 2 Bytes representing unsigned int 65340 or -195 respectively or are you referring to a character array of 4 byte containing the ascii or whatever codes of F, F, 3 and C? I assume it is 2 bytes only.

Comment: representing -195, forgot to add the preceding '0x'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually quite a difficult problem!

This was about the 20th thing I tried, and seems to work ok:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:"FF3C" length:4];
NSString *string = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
string = [@"0x" stringByAppendingString:string];

unsigned short value;
sscanf([string UTF8String], "%hx", &value);

NSLog(@"%d", value);
```

and the output is:

> 65340

Comment: See updated post, I get '804061168' for '0xF0FF', should have gotten '-3 841'

Comment: 16 bit is not exactly 4 bytes. NSUInteger either represents unsigned long or unsingend int. We are looking for unsinged short I guess.

Comment: With 'length:2' I get '<fcff> = 803536892'

Comment: how to get signed bytes here?

Answer (score 2):

I found an easy way to do that, check if it work for you.

I did this:

```
int value;
[characteristic.value getBytes:&value length:2];
```

And just change the length to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I never did that myself. However, this should work assuming your 2 byte data is in myData:

```
unsined short myInt = (int) [myData bytes];
```

You may want to test wether myData.lenght really equals 2.

Comment: 'NSData' do not have 'getBytes'

Comment: It does. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/getBytes:  And it should have getBytes as it has a bytes property. [myData bytes] would work as well.

Comment: All right, it is depricated. [myData bytes] would work anyway. I'll fix it. Thanks.

Comment: I get an error: 'No visible @interface for `NSData` declares the selector `getBytes`'

Comment: Yes, please use myData.bytes or [myData bytes]. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: With your suggestion I get e.g '1428560' for '0xFCFF' (expected -769)

Comment: I changed the type to unsigned short. Unsigned short cannot even carry 1428560. How exactly does your NSLog look like or how did you come that you get 1428560?

Comment: See updated code. My log looks like `2012-08-07 10:38:35.728 Copter[11007:707] Converted value: 803536894`

Comment: Courious. ´Try NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Converted value: %i", (int) myInt]);´ NSLog (respectively printf behind it) may be confused by %i, wich expects an int, and myInt being unsigned short. Frankly, I am a bit uncertain now.

Comment: I am really incertain myself. Please see updated console in question. It seems even though I just receive 0, I get variable values on the converted output.