# How to get data from CBCharacteristics?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

[image]

Can somebody help me to extract the data from value field in

I want to just show bytes data.
     Read method

```
            public async Task<NSData> ReadValue(CBPeripheral peripheral, CBCharacteristic characteristic)
    {
        BTProgressHUD.Show("Loading...", 1000, ProgressHUD.MaskType.Gradient);
        var taskCompletion = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        var task = taskCompletion.Task;
        EventHandler<CBCharacteristicEventArgs> handler = (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Characteristic.UUID?.Uuid == characteristic.UUID?.Uuid)
            {
               // e.Characteristic.Value = characteristic.Value;
                taskCompletion.SetResult(true);
            }
        };

        try
        {
            peripheral.UpdatedCharacterteristicValue += handler;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(900);

            peripheral.ReadValue(characteristic);

            BTProgressHUD.Dismiss();
            await Task.Delay(200);

            return characteristic.Value;

        }
        finally
        {
```

//to get the updated characteristics value.

```
            peripheral.UpdatedCharacterteristicValue -= handler;
            BTProgressHUD.Dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you do a readValue and get the delegate method to be called?

Comment: @Larme  yes i did.

Comment: And that's the screenshot from where? From that delegate method? Could you print exactly the value of the bytes (it's 87 length), not only a screenshof of the debugguer, because value should be a Data, not a String, so there is some kind of interpretation, and what is it supposed to be?

Comment: {<CBCharacteristic: 0x28391e040, UUID = 0000AADD-8E22-4541-9D4C-21EDAE82ED19, properties = 0x2, value = {length = 87, bytes = 0x22222222 22222222 22222222 22222222 ... 22222222 22222222 }, notifying = NO>}

Comment: I need to get bytes = 0x22222222 22222222 22222222 22222222 ... 22222222 22222222 to be displayed

Comment: Value is a `Data` (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/corebluetooth.cbcharacteristic.value?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12#CoreBluetooth_CBCharacteristic_Value), just print it. Do no think that the debugger is not interpreting the value.

Comment: But if i am trying to get the characteristics.value it is {""""""""""""""""""""""""""""}.Note this characteristics is cbcharacteristics not cbmutable charateristics

Comment: It doesn't matter. CBMutableCharacteristic is just a mutable version of CBCharacteristic Could you add code, and from what method you are reading the value?.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert it to string

```
var value = characteristic.Value;
NSString dataValue = NSString.FromData(value, NSStringEncoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: -As u can see the value field is empty.characteristic.Value is {"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""} but CBCharacteristics have the field value from which i need to get the byte=0x22222222222 data and display it

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40269248/how-to-get-exact-value-from-a-cbcharacteristic

Comment: the problem here is characteristic.Value is {"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""}